# Что значит эта ошибка?

Tags: ios, swift

В консоли выходит такая ошибка:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release

Хотя приложение работает.

Что значит эта ошибка и как ее устранить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос уже поднимался [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302019/getting-a-this-application-is-modifying-the-autolayout-engine-error)

> Вы получаете предупреждение если выполнение фонового потока совпадает
>   с главным потоком, который ответственен за обновление
>   пользовательского интерфейса и должен реагировать на пользовательские
>   события.
>   Он должен быть помещен в другом потоке, что позволяет обновлять
>   пользовательский интерфейс:

**Swift Version**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    // code here
})
```

**Objective-C Version**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // code here
});
```

Comment: плохой английский, попробую понять. спасибо